# Is there any way to generate a function whose graph would give a line of finite length?

Tags: differential-geometry

Is there any way to generate a function whose graph would give a line of finite length?

We know that we can generate functions which give combined graphs of functions by taking $(g (x)-y)(f (x)-y)=0$.
Can we get a function which gives a graph of finite lengh?

Comment: Of finite length... over all the reals?

Comment: If you allow yourself parametric equations $(x,y)=(\sin t, \sin t)$ will do it.

Comment: If picewise functions count it would be trivial

Comment: Nope not piecewise function. Infact my question is if we can define piecewise functions with some real mathematical expression. Like we represent some functions with taylor series. Like that can we get some way to draw a given finite shape with a mathematical expression?

Comment: @Brilli just speculating here, but what about taking the Fourier series of said picewise function? I know for sure that you can draw pretty much any shape you want what a Fourier series

Answer (score 1):

As your example involves an implicitly defined function, how about the implicit function
$$x^2+y^2=1,$$
whose graph is the unit circle?

Comment: it should be $x^2+y^2=1$

Comment: Of course, silly me.